# Trouble with Composer Autoloading: not loading all files

Tags: php, composer-php

I've been building a web app of my own for a while now, but have completely hit against the wall with a fatal error in PHP.

Short story: I'm working on the login / user section of the project. `login.php` handles the login stuff, while `student.php` handles the account stuff.

When trying to complete `doLogin`, I achieve the fatal error that states `student::getProfile()` is an "undefined method". `student::getProfile()` is called as part of `validate()` inside the `login` class.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

**EDIT:** With the help of @deceze I've been able to narrow the issue down to the fact that Composer isn't autoloading *all* of my classes; only some. Would anyone be able to assist?

**EDIT 2:** I checked `autoload_classmap.php` which was generated by Composer, and all my core classes and models are listed! If they're listed in the classmap, why isn't Composer loaded them?

---

project directory

```
application/
    config/
    controller/
    core/
        (core items such as auth, app, view rendering + view controller)
    model/
        (speciality functions such as login, registration + user)
    view/
public/
    index.php
    .htaccess
vendor/
    autoload.php
composer.json
.htaccess

note: /public/index.php calls `require '../vendor/autoload.php';`
```

---

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": [
            "application/core/",
            "application/model/"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: include that student.php file inside login.php at the start.

Comment: @deceze `Call to undefined method student::getProfile() in login.php`

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com it's already 'included' using Composer's PSR-4 autoloader.

Comment: This *should* work. The only explanation really is that the file is not being included.

Comment: **NOTE**: in login.php instead of `$result = login::validate($student_email, $student_password);` USE `$result = self::validate($student_email, $student_password);` Its better approach

Comment: @deceze that's what I've been saying to myself over and over again, it's driving me crazy. I'm 110% positive it's included through Composer as if I try to include it myself I obtain a "Cannot redeclare" error.

Comment: Simply confirm whether the file is being included by adding an `echo "I'm included!"` to it. The only other explanation would be namespaces, and/or invisible characters in your code somewhere; i.e. the name of the class or function is actually different.

Comment: @RyanVincent No I'm not using NameSpaces. Should I be?

Comment: @DamianWorsdell can you pls do what deceze says?

Comment: In validate method you're missing return $result

Comment: @deceze @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com I've added an `error_log("xxx")` to each of my class files, and it seems only *some* of them are being autoloaded by Composer. I'm totally at a loss. My composer.json file is simply ` "autoload": { "psr-4": { "": ["application/core/", "application/model/"] } } ` . `student.php` and `login.php` are both in the `/model/` directory.

Comment: So you've narrowed down the problem to a problem with your autoloader. Please rewrite the question accordingly to focus on that, this isn't going to be solved in comments.

Comment: @deceze thanks! Question updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much tedious searching, I've found the error in my ways - and it's pretty silly!

I have a controller named `student` while also having a model named `student`, and as such I was **inadvertently trying to call a class that's technically already being called**. As such, it was looking in the first `student` class for the function, rather than the other which actually contained that specific function.

Composer doesn't realise if there is already a class with that name pre-declared, and just negates it without any entry in the PHP error log.

To avoid this error - and any further class name mixups in the future - I decided to use individual namespaces for both `core` classes and `model` classes. This separates those classes into 'sub-sections' as such, allowing the use of classes named the same (albeit in different namespaces).

---

[PHP Manual: Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

[Sitepoint: How to Use PHP Namespaces, Part 1: The Basics](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics/)